# What kind of hardware do companies use for backing up their data?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, hardware-failure

From what I've learned, Tapes (LTO-5) is used, but I'm not sure if there is anything else out there that is a better alternative.

What kind of hardware do companies use for backing up their data?

Comment: Questions that just ask for a list are not a good fit on SU.  If you are also asking what makes one better than another, that is very localized to specific needs and opinion based.  A comprehensive comparison of alternatives would be excessively broad.  This might be better as a discussion topic, either in chat here or on a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use cloud style solution such as `Openstack Swift`.  (https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Swift https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack#Object_Storage_.28Swift.29) Other good example is `Ceph`. (http://ceph.com/)

That way large number of basic storage hardware can be combined into single fault tolerant storage cloud. These cloud solutions also make it easy to scale up when need for storage increases.

This idea could also be taken further and storage could bought from public cloud. From providers like `Amazon` storage space is cheap now days. (Network speeds might be bigger problem if there is lot of data that changes regularly.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are they limited to just those two solutions?

Comment: The are other solutions too, for example Gluster. Also there commercial solutions from companies like NetApp.